# Unable to get selected row index of gridview in javascript

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have got a gridview with certain rows/columns and an edit button for each row. When the edit button is clicked, it opens a popup window with a textbox and a button. I want to know the index of the selected row on click of the button inside the popup. I added code like so

```
var table = document.getElementById('<%= gvTimeSlots.ClientID%>');
var Row;
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    Row = table.rows[i];
    alert(Row);
}
```

But the alert gives me "Undefined". What am I missing here?

Comment: Start iterating from 0, not from 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my fix..

```
function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        alert("RowIndex: " + rowIndex);
        return false;
    }
```

I am calling this function in **Onclientclick** event of the link button.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" Visible="true">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewTimeSlots" runat="server" Text="Edit" ForeColor="Blue" OnClick="lnkViewTimeSlots_click" OnClientClick="return GetSelectedRow(this); javascript:shouldsubmit=true;" CausesValidation="false" Style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can get the row index like

```
function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        alert("RowIndex: " + lnk.$index;);//This lnk.$index will get the index 
        return false;
    }
```