# How to get cell index of gridview on clicking in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying this code but in the hidden field its always showing empty value.

```
$('#gvshowreport>tbody>tr>td').click(function () {

var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

var title = $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(col).text();

$('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(title);

$('#<%= HiddenField2.ClientID %>').val(col);
```

In the Code Behind:

```
 string headerRowText = HiddenField1.Value;

 string s = HiddenField2.Value;
```

Comment: You want the Row Index?

Comment: I need the column index on clicking particular cell of gridview

Comment: Check if this is useful..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643524/unable-to-get-selected-row-index-of-gridview-in-javascript/16643811#16643811

Comment: @Aishvarya that code is to get row index. Moreover am not using boundfield because columns will be dynamically bind from database